# HTTP to HTTPS Redirection Issue

Tags: php, apache, https

I want to redirect http requests to https node.

I tried,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Please find below few test results, I executed,

http://sample.mydomane.co/ **redirected to** https://sample.mydomane.co/

// Worked as expected

http://sample.mydomane.co/api-docs/ **not redirected to** 
     https://sample.mydomane.co/api-docs/

//Didn't work as expected

**EDIT:** This is my `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    #Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(api-docs|docs)($|/) - [L] # HERE IS THE PROBLEM I THINK

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # redirect all http -> https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

</IfModule>
```

Please let me know how to achieve or fix this.

Comment: I edited the question to include the .htaccess file. Please note the comment "HERE IS THE PROBLEM I THINK".

Answer (score 1):

I use with success the following rule, note the difference of the regex pattern

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domainname/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: I used this but not worked for me in the case of http://sample.mydomane.co/api-docs/. I have edited the question to include my .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Apache Wiki

> http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS